# In OpenCV createTrackbar function what is the 6th paramter(User data) how it will be useful.(Please find the parameters in the explanation)

Tags: opencv, void-pointers, trackbar

C++: int createTrackbar(const string& trackbarname, const string& winname, int* value, int count, TrackbarCallback onChange=0, void* userdata=0)
In above mention function what is the userdata how it will used in the callback function

Comment: The reference is pretty clear about this - http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=createtrackbar#int createTrackbar(const string& trackbarname, const string& winname, int* value, int count, TrackbarCallback onChange, void* userdata) next time, please consider reading it before asking here...

Comment: I have a doubt in that particular parameter. I couldn't get back my value after dereference it.That's Why I raised the question.Anyhow thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that param is useful together with a callback function, which looks like this:

```
void onChange (int trackpos , void *userdata);
```

you can e.g pass (the address of) an image to it:

```
Mat img; // e.g from a webcam
int b=3; // blur value
namedWindow("win");
createTrackBar("blur","win", &b, 100, onChange, (void*)(&img) );
```

and use it inside the callback:

```
void onChange (int trackpos , void *userdata)
{
   Mat img = *((Mat*)userdata); // 1st cast, then deref
   Mat b2;
   blur( img,b2, Size(trackpos,trackpos));
   imshow("win",b2);
   waitKey(10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.In my call back function I didn't type cast it before dereference it.Because of that I misunderstood the concept.Thanks for your information.

Comment: ah, ok. common pitfall ;)